# Unable to show graphs in android

Tags: android, eclipse, charts

I am trying to create a graph in android using achartengine library.
After getting run of an emulator its just showing **"sorry your app unexpectedly closed.try again.force close"**

I have a doubt only on Manifest.xml file, is my manifest file wight?if not please make me clear.

*Please find my sources,manifest.xml and logcat for reference*

**LOGCAT**

```
08-22 11:47:05.763: D/AndroidRuntime(537): Shutting down VM
08-22 11:47:05.775: W/dalvikvm(537): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
08-22 11:47:05.783: E/AndroidRuntime(537): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-22 11:47:05.783: E/AndroidRuntime(537): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.graphs_test/com.example.graphs_test.MainActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.graphs_test/org.achartengine.GraphicalActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
08-22 11:47:05.783: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
08-22 11:47:05.783: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
08-22 11:47:05.783: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
08-22 11:47:05.783: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
08-22 11:47:05.783: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-22 11:47:05.783: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-22 11:47:05.783: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-22 11:47:05.783: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-22 11:47:05.783: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-22 11:47:05.783: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-22 11:47:05.783: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-22 11:47:05.783: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-22 11:47:05.783: E/AndroidRuntime(537): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.graphs_test/org.achartengine.GraphicalActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
08-22 11:47:05.783: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1404)
08-22 11:47:05.783: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
08-22 11:47:05.783: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2817)
08-22 11:47:05.783: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2923)
08-22 11:47:05.783: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at com.example.graphs_test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
08-22 11:47:05.783: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-22 11:47:05.783: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
08-22 11:47:05.783: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  ... 11 more
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.graphs_test"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent intent = buildIntent();
    startActivity(intent);         
}

public Intent buildIntent() {
     int[] values = new int[] { 5, 15, 25, 50, 75 };       
     String[] bars = new String[] {"Francesca's",  "King of Clubs", 
                                "Zen Lounge", "Tied House", "Molly Magees"};
     int[] colors = new int[] { Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.MAGENTA, 
                                  Color.YELLOW, Color.CYAN };

     CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries("Pie Chart");  
     DefaultRenderer dr = new DefaultRenderer();  

     for (int v=0; v<5; v++){    
         series.add(bars[v], values[v]);
         SimpleSeriesRenderer r = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
         r.setColor(colors[v]);
         dr.addSeriesRenderer(r);
     }
     dr.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
     dr.setZoomEnabled(true);
     dr.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
     return ChartFactory.getPieChartIntent(    
                             this, series, dr, "Pie of bars");
   }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Thanks for your precious time!..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`org.achartengine.GraphicalActivity` wasn't found in your manifest because it is part of the library.

Add the following line to your *project.properties* file to enable automatic merging of manifests.

```
manifestmerger.enabled=true
```

[image: project.properties file]

**Edit:**

I thought achartengine was a library project. Turns out it's a JAR.

You need to add the activity to your manifest:

```
<activity android:name="org.achartengine.GraphicalActivity" />
```

Comment: can you tell me where have i to mention this line manifestmerger.enabled=true in manifest.xml file

Comment: Not the manifest file, but the **project.properties** file. Check out the screenshot.

Comment: even though if i followed your suggestion, the emulator showing the same error on the logcat.

Comment: make sure you have the latest ADT plugin

Comment: i checked it out.I am having the latest ADT plugins

Comment: Ok, all this time I thought this was a library project. Turns out it's a JAR. Check out my updated answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15648/discussion-between-rohith-and-benito)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the activity to AndroidManifest.xml like this :

```
<activity android:name="org.achartengine.GraphicalActivity"></activity>
```